# calculate the value of an obj key while using different key/values of the same object?

Tags: javascript, object

How can I calculate pageSize.offset from the keys`pageSizes.w/pageSize.h` inside the same object?

```
   var pageSizes = {
              w: parseInt(scope.page.imagewidth),
              h: parseInt(scope.page.imageheight),
              offset: (pageSize.w/pageSize.h)
            }

   console.log('page.offset', pageSizes.offset);
```

currently i'm getting a RefferenceError: pageSize is not defined.

I'm assuming this isn't possible. therefore, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: with leaky assignments and temp vars: var x; {w: x= parseInt(scope.page.imagewidth), offset: w*2}

Comment: There is a difference of one s in pageSizes and pageSize. Better is probably to calculate w, h and offset outside the object and then just create the object from those.

Comment: To avoid having to remember that *offset* is a method and the others are properties, you could use a [*getter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) on *offset* or a [*setter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) that sets its value on the other two properties (being careful of division by zero). Or change the name to *getOffset*.

Comment: @Absor is there a optimization gain in your method?  please post answer w/reason and I can mark it correct?

Comment: @dandavis what does OPD stand for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a function and use `this`

```
var pageSizes = {
          w: parseInt(scope.page.imagewidth, 10), //Dont forget the radix!
          h: parseInt(scope.page.imageheight, 10), //Dont forget the radix!
          offset: function() {
              return this.w/this.h;
          }
        }

console.log('page.offset', pageSizes.offset());
```

Also, dont forget your radix in the `parseInt` function

Comment: Hey is this considered a closure?  still so fuzzy to me?

Comment: @tyme has already given the answer, sorry i didnt see this before posting mine

Comment: @Absor above said it would be better to not do it this way?  is he proper in this idea?

Comment: This is actually better if w and h will change at any point (and might be overall).

Answer (score 3):

apparently this works in firefox, opera, safari, chrome, and even IE9:

```
var pageSizes ={
          w: parseInt(scope.page.imagewidth, 10), //Dont forget the radix!
          h: parseInt(scope.page.imageheight, 10), //Dont forget the radix!
           get offset () {
              return this.w/this.h;
          }
 };
```

it's like the method one, but you don't have to call it, keeping it acting like the other properties.

console-friendly version:

```
    var pageSizes ={
              w: 5,
              h: 10,
               get offset () {
                  return this.w/this.h;
              }
     };

JSON.stringify(pageSizes); // == "{"w":5,"h":10,"offset":0.5}"
```

i'd always used Object.defineProperty (ODP) for getters and setters, but this seems to be a lot more supported than i thought. you learn something every day. it looks like a typo, what with the missing  colon and "function" and all, but it works. very cool.

thank's to robG for his comment, which made me check the ref again.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Example:_Defining_a_getter_with_the_get_operator for details

Comment: nm it did work with that get function.  it wont work in ie8 tho right?

Comment: IE9 up, afaik; it cannot be polyfilled because it's a syntax error to the jscript engine.

Answer (score 0):

Function has refence to special keyword "this" that points to Current Scope(or protypical scope of parent till global scope) or current Object Instance , Here Points to PageSizes Object
Use this

```
      var pageSizes = {
      w: parseInt(scope.page.imagewidth),
      h: parseInt(scope.page.imageheight),
      offset: function() {
          return this.w/this.h;
      }
    }
```

and then chnage this line , as offset it not an property it is a function now

```
    console.log('page.offset', pageSizes.offset);
```

to

```
   console.log('page.offset', pageSizes.offset());
```